# Missing field from core data import

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data

I am having an insanely frustrating problem with core data. In the app I am designing a view where the user can search through songs by their writers, composers, etc. I am storing this data in an `NSManagedObject` subclass. As the data in the app doesn't change, I create the database in another short program and then move the `.sqlite` file to the bundle of the app.

When I fetch all `Person` objects from the database, something strange happens. All of the Person objects show up, but some of the `name` fields in the objects are somehow set to `nil`. Only the objects where the person's role is "Composer" seem to have this issue.

What makes this so much of a problem is that I have verified that the names of these entities are in the sqlite file. I can print all objects at the end of the import program (the one that creates the database) and get the correct info. I also thought that perhaps the file system was doing something to the file when I copied it over, but I can open the sqlite file from the command line and manually get the names of composers there as well.

Has anyone had a similar problem?

Comment: Did you add ` -com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 3` to your debug scheme and a break point shortly after the line where you read the `Person`? What does CoreData see when it accesses the store?

Comment: I hadn't but thanks for that tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a number of hours being frustrated by this the answer was glaringly simple. There was a point a few days ago where some of the data was corrupted in a transfer and that corrupt database was put in the app bundle. The app caches the database if it is not already each time it runs. So all of the time I've been trying to get this to work I may have had it right, the database in the bundle was just not being copied in because there was already a (bad) one there.

The app just needed to be un- and reinstalled.